# Checkboxes in a ListView that uses a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

My `MainActivity` contains a `ListView` and a menu item which launches `DetailsActivity`. `DetailsActivity` can add items to the database which populates the `ListView`. Here's a description of the use case that causes problems for me:

1. Start `MainActivity`.
2. Check some items in the list.
3. Launch `DetailsActivity`.
4. Add items to the database.
5. Press the back button to return to `MainActivity`.

At the end of this sequence, none of the checks from step 2 remain, even though I attempt to restore their state.

MainActivity.onPause() and MainActivity.onResume():

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    this.savedSelection = this.adapter.getSelection();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // restore default header state
    CheckedTextView headerCheck = (CheckedTextView) this.headerView
            .findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
    headerCheck.setChecked(false);

    boolean[] newSelection = new boolean[this.adapter.getCount()];

    if (this.savedSelection != null) {
        // copy old selection array into new selection array
        int numSelected = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.savedSelection.length; i++) {
            newSelection[i] = this.savedSelection[i];

            if (newSelection[i]) {
                numSelected++;
            }

            View row = this.listView.getChildAt(i + 1);

            if (row != null) {
                CheckedTextView checkbox = (CheckedTextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
                checkbox.setChecked(newSelection[i]);

                TextView playerText = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.player_name_text_view);
                Log.d(TAG, playerText.getText().toString() + " checked? "
                        + checkbox.isChecked());
            }
        }

        // restore header state
        if (numSelected == newSelection.length) {
            headerCheck.setChecked(true);
        }

    }

    // restore state
    this.adapter.setSelection(newSelection);
}
```

MyAdapter.getView():

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
    final Activity curActivity = (Activity) this.context;

    // restore selection
    if (this.selection != null) {
        ctv.setChecked(this.selection[position]);
    }

    // set listener
    ctv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckedTextView cview = (CheckedTextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkmark);
            cview.toggle();
            BaseballCardAdapter.this.selection[position] = cview
                    .isChecked();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                curActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        }

    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: can you add the 'getView' code you use in your adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it would work better if you used a savedInstanceState, and set this.savedSelection in the onCreate method. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.putBooleanArray(SOME_CONSTANT_STRING,this.savedSelection);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (savedInstanceState!=null) {
      this.savedSelection=savedInstanceState.getBooleanArray(SOME_CONSTANT_STRING);
   }
}
```

I believe the rest of your code should work.

Comment: This works fine for when the activity is destroyed and recreated. It doesn't help for the situation when the activity is only paused and later resumed.